# R: Greenhouse-Geisser in Anova from car package

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

i have a question concerning the output from {car} Anova. I want to run a simple 2x2 repeated measures ANOVA using the multivariate approach. I can run the (modified) example from the Anova {car} help page:

```
phase <- factor(rep(c("pretest", "posttest", "followup"), c(5, 5, 5)),
                levels=c("pretest", "posttest", "followup"))
hour <- ordered(rep(1:5, 3))
idata <- data.frame(phase, hour)
idata

mod.ok <- lm(cbind(pre.1, pre.2, pre.3, pre.4, pre.5, 
                post.1, post.2, post.3, post.4, post.5, 
                fup.1, fup.2, fup.3, fup.4, fup.5) ~  1, 
            data=OBrienKaiser)

(av.ok <- Anova(mod.ok, idata=idata, idesign=~phase*hour) )
b<-summary(av.ok)
```

Which gives the following (shortened) output

```
Univariate Type III Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                SS num Df Error SS den Df        F    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 7260.0      1   603.33     15 180.4972 9.100e-10 ***
phase        167.5      2   169.17     30  14.8522 3.286e-05 ***
hour         106.3      4    73.71     60  21.6309 4.360e-11 ***
phase:hour    11.1      8   122.92    120   1.3525    0.2245    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


Mauchly Tests for Sphericity

        Test statistic  p-value
phase             0.70470 0.086304
hour              0.11516 0.000718
phase:hour        0.01139 0.027376


Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt Corrections
for Departure from Sphericity

            GG eps Pr(>F[GG])    
phase      0.77202  0.0001891 ***
hour       0.49842  1.578e-06 ***
phase:hour 0.51297  0.2602357    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

            HF eps Pr(>F[HF])    
phase      0.84367  0.0001089 ***
hour       0.57470  3.161e-07 ***
phase:hour 0.73031  0.2439922    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, with my data (see below) the Greenhouse-Geisser output is missing:

```
    h2 <-
structure(list(A1neg = c(-8.427556992, 1.20452559, -14.331842422, 
-10.428559303, 1.750265002, 9.388166428, 0.790130436, -1.592002392, 
0.539065838, -3.758603573, 8.391399384), B1neg = c(-12.188085556, 
-1.964554906, -12.247328758, -7.326891422, -0.961694896, -1.048453212, 
-4.225459576, 0.173920691, 1.876976371, -9.11947155, -1.706287026
), A1pos = c(-0.660317183, 3.498036146, 22.003242493, 19.905063629, 
-3.124288321, 11.968006134, 5.838645935, 5.140467644, 5.154311657, 
2.298083067, 1.164232969), B1pos = c(-12.805168152, -1.550003886, 
45.990013123, 15.915545464, -1.67797184, 7.565258026, 10.635170937, 
12.769438744, 11.738276482, 4.544145107, 0.230011433)), .Names = c("A1neg", 
"B1neg", "A1pos", "B1pos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"11", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", "71", "81", "91", "101"))


condition <- ordered(rep(c("A", "B"), c(2)),
                 levels=c("A", "B"))
reg <- factor(rep(c("neg", "pos"), c(2,2)),
            levels=c("neg", "pos"))
idata<-data.frame(condition, reg)
idata

mod.ok<-lm(cbind( A1neg,B1neg,A1pos,B1pos) ~ 1, data=h2)
(av.ok<-Anova(mod.ok, idata=idata, idesign=~condition*reg))
summary(av.ok)
```

This gives:

```
Univariate Type III Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                SS num Df Error SS den Df      F  Pr(>F)  
(Intercept)    233.35      1   995.14     10 2.3449 0.15669  
condition        3.32      1   373.00     10 0.0891 0.77143  
reg           1220.66      1  2135.77     10 5.7153 0.03791 *
condition:reg   62.48      1   176.90     10 3.5318 0.08963 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
>
```

Do you have any ideas, what went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nothing went wrong.** The program did exactly what it was meant to do. It's because you only have a 2x2 factorial design in your example. Mauchly's test for sphericity compares variances of differences between levels of repeated measures factors. Another way of looking at it is the covariance matrix in the repeated measures design. If you have a 2x2 design, there is only **one** covariance, look at the following variance-covariance matrix (where $A1$ and $A2$ are the repeated measurements):

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
Var(A1) & Cov(A1, A2)  \\
Cov(A2, A1)  & Var(A2)  \end{array} \right) 
$$

There is only one covariance (covariance is symmetric), namely $Cov(A1,A2)=Cov(A2,A1)$. Hence, there is only one variance of the difference $Var(A1-A2)$. So: **in a 2x2 design, the sphericity assumption is always met**. That's why the function `summary.Anova.mlm` doesn't calculate Mauchly's test and no Greenhouse-Geisser corrections are given in the output. [Here](http://psychologicalstatistics.blogspot.ch/2006/05/what-is-all-this-stuff-about.html) is a very good explanation of sphericity and your problem is also mentioned (section "Complications").

Look what happens if we add another level to your example (I made up the data for "C"):

```
h2 <- structure(list(A1neg = c(-8.427556992, 1.20452559, -14.331842422, 
                               -10.428559303, 1.750265002, 9.388166428, 0.790130436, -1.592002392, 
                               0.539065838, -3.758603573, 8.391399384),
                     B1neg = c(-12.188085556, 
                               -1.964554906, -12.247328758, -7.326891422, -0.961694896, -1.048453212, 
                               -4.225459576, 0.173920691, 1.876976371, -9.11947155, -1.706287026),
                     C1neg = c(1.750265002, 0.539065838, 1.20452559, 8.391399384, -3.758603573, 
                               -7.326891422, 0.790130436, -9.11947155, -1.592002392, -12.188085556, 
                               -10.428559303),
                     A1pos = c(-0.660317183, 3.498036146, 22.003242493, 19.905063629, 
                               -3.124288321, 11.968006134, 5.838645935, 5.140467644, 5.154311657, 
                               2.298083067, 1.164232969),
                     B1pos = c(-12.805168152, -1.550003886, 
                               45.990013123, 15.915545464, -1.67797184, 7.565258026, 10.635170937, 
                               12.769438744, 11.738276482, 4.544145107, 0.230011433),
                     C1pos= c(-1.550003886, 1.164232969, 11.738276482, 5.838645935, -12.805168152, 
                              -0.660317183, 22.003242493, 19.905063629, 0.230011433, 7.565258026, 
                              5.154311657)),

                .Names = c("A1neg", 
                           "B1neg",
                           "C1neg",
                           "A1pos",
                           "B1pos",
                           "C1pos"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                    "11", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", "71", "81", "91", "101"))

condition <- ordered(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(2)),
                     levels=c("A", "B", "C"))
reg <- factor(rep(c("neg", "pos"), c(3,3)),
              levels=c("neg", "pos"))
idata<-data.frame(condition, reg)
idata

mod.ok<-lm(cbind(A1neg,B1neg,C1neg, A1pos,B1pos,C1pos) ~ 1, data=h2)
(av.ok<-Anova(mod.ok, idata=idata, idesign=~condition*reg))
summary(av.ok)
```

Now the output shows Mauchly's test and the Greenhouse-Geisser correction.

```
Univariate Type III Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                   SS num Df Error SS den Df      F  Pr(>F)  
(Intercept)    248.91      1  1158.47     10 2.1486 0.17342  
condition       20.52      2   875.91     20 0.2342 0.79333  
reg           1571.69      1  1789.74     10 8.7817 0.01421 *
condition:reg   82.27      2  1244.02     20 0.6613 0.52710  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Mauchly Tests for Sphericity

              Test statistic p-value
condition            0.97043 0.87365
condition:reg        0.48792 0.03959


Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt Corrections
 for Departure from Sphericity

               GG eps Pr(>F[GG])
condition     0.97128     0.7872
condition:reg 0.66134     0.4719

               HF eps Pr(>F[HF])
condition     1.20188     0.7933
condition:reg 0.72312     0.4838
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the explanation and for providing the link.

Comment: @RubenReal You're welcome. Glad I could help.