# ANOVA does not show sphericity test

Tags: r, sphericity

I have a dataset, `df`, which I converted to wide format and then used the `Anova` function (in the `car` package) to analyze the data.

```
dfW1         <- reshape(df, v.names="score", timevar="WTH1", idvar=c("id","BTW","WTH2"),
                        direction = "wide")
dfSPFp.qrW   <- reshape(dfW1, v.names=c("score.0", "score.1"), timevar="WTH2", 
                        idvar=c("id", "BTW"), direction="wide")
fitSPFp.qr   <- lm(cbind(score.0.0, score.1.0, score.0.1, score.1.1) ~ BTW, 
                   data=dfSPFp.qrW)
inSPFp.qr    <- expand.grid(WTH1=gl(2, 1, labels=c("0","1")), 
                            WTH2=gl(2, 1, labels=c("0","1")) )
AnovaSPFp.qr <- Anova(fitSPFp.qr, idata=inSPFp.qr, idesign=~WTH1*WTH2)
print(summary(AnovaSPFp.qr, multivariate=FALSE, univariate=TRUE))
```

And the result:

```
Univariate Type II Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                   SS num Df Error SS den Df       F    Pr(>F)      
(Intercept)    0.0000      1   32.691     25  0.0000   1.00000     
BTW           15.4270      4   32.691     25  2.9494   0.03991 *  
WTH1          13.0875      1   14.809     25 22.0943 8.099e-05 ***
BTW:WTH1       5.0237      4   14.809     25  2.1203   0.10815    
WTH2          11.1769      1    9.657     25 28.9338 1.402e-05 ***
BTW:WTH2       1.4321      4    9.657     25  0.9268   0.46420    
WTH1:WTH2      7.0250      1    7.959     25 22.0653 8.164e-05 ***
BTW:WTH1:WTH2  1.7118      4    7.959     25  1.3442   0.28142
```

And it does not show Geisser - Greenhouse or Huynh - Feldt result. I read the topic at: [R: Greenhouse-Geisser in Anova from car package](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59192/r-greenhouse-geisser-in-anova-from-car-package), but do not see why this happened. I want to test the sphericity of my data (using Geisser-Greenhouse and Huynh-Feldt test). How can I do it?

My data:

```
str (df)
'data.frame': 120 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id     : Factor w/ 30 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ... 
 $ BTW    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ WTH1   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ WTH2   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ score: num  -1.06 -0.678 1.194 1.94 -1.06 ...

df <- read.table(text="id BTW WTH1 WTH2       score
                1   1    0    0 -1.16055841
                1   1    0    1 -0.78485342
                1   1    1    0  1.05951654
                1   1    1    1  1.79384902
                7   2    0    0 -0.44330343
                7   2    0    1  1.87923652
                7   2    1    0 -0.44330343
                7   2    1    1 -0.42622593
               13   3    0    0 -1.16055841
               13   3    0    1 -0.22129593
               13   3    1    0  0.29102906
               13   3    1    1  0.71796654
               19   4    0    0 -0.40914843
               19   4    0    1  0.49595905
               19   4    1    0  1.69138402
               19   4    1    1  0.35933905
               25   5    0    0 -0.30668343
               25   5    0    1 -0.40914843
               25   5    1    0  1.84508152
               25   5    1    1 -0.13590843
                2   1    0    0 -1.16055841
                2   1    0    1 -1.10932591
                2   1    1    0 -0.93855091
                2   1    1    1 -1.02393841
                8   2    0    0 -1.01629043
                8   2    0    1  0.11668190
                8   2    1    0  0.26631975
                8   2    1    1  0.82211750
               14   3    0    0 -0.18259381
               14   3    0    1  0.95037852
               14   3    1    0  1.20690056
               14   3    1    1  1.31378474
               20   4    0    0 -0.54600003
               20   4    0    1  1.50617627
               20   4    1    0 -1.03766727
               20   4    1    1  1.67719096
               26   5    0    0 -0.73839156
               26   5    0    1 -0.67426105
               26   5    1    0 -1.16592829
               26   5    1    1  0.35182710
                3   1    0    0 -1.27281247
                3   1    0    1  1.50617627
                3   1    1    0  1.10001638
                3   1    1    1 -0.20397065
                9   2    0    0 -1.10179778
                9   2    0    1 -0.97353676
                9   2    1    0 -0.82389890
                9   2    1    1 -1.08042094
               15   3    0    0 -1.37219594
               15   3    0    1 -0.55904279
               15   3    1    0 -0.28257072
               15   3    1    1  0.12400586
               21   4    0    0 -0.38014910
               21   4    0    1  0.25411036
               21   4    1    0 -0.07115090
               21   4    1    1 -0.05488784
               27   5    0    0 -0.67288423
               27   5    0    1 -0.21751847
               27   5    1    0 -0.64035811
               27   5    1    1  0.35168874
                4   1    0    0 -1.22582837
                4   1    0    1  0.15653198
                4   1    1    0  0.62816081
                4   1    1    1 -0.68914730
               10   2    0    0 -1.06319774
               10   2    0    1 -0.39641216
               10   2    1    0 -0.02236171
               10   2    1    1  0.23784730
               16   3    0    0 -0.64035811
               16   3    0    1  1.18110495
               16   3    1    0  2.14062567
               16   3    1    1  3.21398783
               22   4    0    0 -0.59035895
               22   4    0    1  0.04005773
               22   4    1    0 -0.29091103
               22   4    1    1 -0.22786936
               28   5    0    0 -1.34685897
               28   5    0    1 -1.25229646
               28   5    1    0 -1.28381730
               28   5    1    1 -1.03165063
                5   1    0    0 -1.37837980
                5   1    0    1  0.40254732
                5   1    1    0  0.48134940
                5   1    1    1  0.81231816
               11   2    0    0 -1.40990063
               11   2    0    1  1.04872441
               11   2    1    0 -0.27515061
               11   2    1    1  0.35526607
               17   3    0    0 -0.35395270
               17   3    0    1  1.41121400
               17   3    1    0  2.18347443
               17   3    1    1  1.89978693
               23   4    0    0 -0.32243186
               23   4    0    1  0.40254732
               23   4    1    0  0.63895357
               23   4    1    1  0.08733898
               29   5    0    0 -0.76451809
               29   5    0    1  0.15770687
               29   5    1    0 -0.01521031
               29   5    1    1 -0.26497957
                6   1    0    0 -1.30248265
                6   1    0    1  0.50354123
                6   1    1    0 -1.20641755
                6   1    1    1 -1.34090869
               12   2    0    0 -1.53303889
               12   2    0    1 -0.09206239
               12   2    1    0 -0.53396185
               12   2    1    1  0.19613291
               18   3    0    0 -1.53303889
               18   3    0    1  0.33062405
               18   3    1    0  1.42576620
               18   3    1    1  1.00307976
               24   4    0    0 -0.47632279
               24   4    0    1  0.71488446
               24   4    1    0  1.71396150
               24   4    1    1  2.34799116
               30   5    0    0 -0.45710977
               30   5    0    1  0.13849385
               30   5    1    0  0.36905009
               30   5    1    1  0.61881936", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with. (We need your `df` or sample / simulated data that will reproduce this.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, I updated my data. Could you please help?

Comment: Isn't your question actually answered at the link you give? It specifically explains that for 2x2 the assumption is automatically met. You'll need to explain why that answer doesn't answer your question. "I don't understand" is not sufficient.

Comment: This is a statistical issue, not a computing one, and should not have closed as off-topic. It's simply a duplicate of the post the OP linked to.